# Print entire PHP array in 1 html table cell

Tags: php

so I'm trying to get my PHP array to print an entire array within one td, so I want the table to look like this:

```
First  ---  Last  ---  Values  
John   --  Smith  --  1,2,4,6
```

`$comp_labs` holds the values (1,2,4,6 for example)

Here's the code I've got at the moment:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "
<td> ".$firstName."</td>
<td> ".$lastName."</td>
<td> ".$comp_labs."</td>
</tr>\n";
echo "</table>";
```

it's printing the name fine but only the last element of the array. I tried looping through just that td printing array[i] like so:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "
<td> ".$firstName."</td>
<td> ".$lastName."</td>
<td> "for($i=0; $i < count($comp_labs); $i++){.$comp_labs[i].}"</td>
</tr>\n";
echo "</table>";
```

but it didn't like that. However if I just Echo out the `$comp_labs` array outside of the table it prints the entire array fine, which I find a little confusing. I've had a look online but every forum I've come across has been people trying to loop through and print 1 value per `t`d, not all values in one `td`.

If anyone is able to help out here I would greatly appreciate it, thanks in advance!

Comment: thats why you dont save them comma delimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
 <td> ".implode(",", $comp_labs )."</td>
```

So it becomes :

```
echo "<tr>
              <td> ".$firstName."</td>
              <td> ".$lastName."</td>
              <td> ".implode(",", $comp_labs)."</td>
     </tr>\n";
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response, I'm getting this error after adding implode: ---
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in --- Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: `$comp_labs` should be array, based on your attempt, I assumed `$comp_labs` is array

Comment: Whoops I accidentally deleted the array initialization line, put it back in and it worked, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Implode the array turning it into a string.

```
$comp  = implode(", ",$comp_labs);
```